# run code in a non-UI thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable, ui-thread

I have an image application and I'm playing music while the images are displayed.
Right now, I have both the functionality in the UI thread.

I want to move the music playback part of it into another thread that is different from the UI thread.

How do I achieve this?

The complication if I use handlers and runnables:

the run() has to have everything that is to be executed
but the music code is scattered all over the place because it is event based and there's a different piece of code to execute each time

so the only way i can implement this with handler and runnable is if I have several runnables each doing a particular function
which means that all the music code will not run in the same thread, they would run in different threads
which is not a good thing.

So how do you do this?

Comment: so were you successful? or do you need some other approach than in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did this successfully. This is what I did. public static void startTrack() {
  PLAYER_STATE = IS_PLAYING;
  //mPlayer.start();
  
  /*Setup the handler and runnable*/
     mMusicHandler = new Handler() {      
     }; 
  
  mMusicRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     Log.d(TAG,"inside Music Runnable");
    try {
     mPlayer.start();  
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     Log.d(TAG,"ILLEGAL STATE-START");
     handleIllegalState();
    }
   }
  };
  mMusicHandler.post(mMusicRunnable);
  
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
 public static void startTrack() {
    PLAYER_STATE = IS_PLAYING;
            /*Setup the handler and runnable*/
    mMusicHandler = new Handler() {         
    }; 

    mMusicRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             Log.d(TAG,"inside Music Runnable");
            try {
                mPlayer.start();        
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,"ILLEGAL STATE-START");
                handleIllegalState();
            }
        }
    };
    mMusicHandler.post(mMusicRunnable);

}
```

So only the start part of the music setup is done on a different thread.

Comment: `new Handler()` gets attached to a thread it is being running on. If `startTrack()` is being called from UI thread, then `mPlayer.start()` will also be called on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a `Service` with a `Binder` - you would then have a handle to it. In `Service` create an `Executor` (singular or multiple `Thread`s in pool - depends on your application structure and events you have; so does a `Queue` implementation) and then just pass music events to the executor.